# How to disable modifier behavior of option key?

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to create some shortcuts in skhd via option keys. I'm also using yabai, so one of my bindings looks like

`option - h: yabai -m window --focus west`

but when I press option + h in an application, a character is printed (˙ in this case) and my shortcut goes kaput. How do I disable this modifier behavior for the option key? I'm using macos ventura and dvorak keyboard.

Comment: Do other opt/letter keys work correctly? `˙` on opt/h is the correct character.

Comment: @Tetsujin it is the correct character but shouldn't it focus the window on the west rather than printing that character? I've verified that yabai / skhd are running when I type those

Comment: It depends on what intercepts it first, which is why I asked about other opt combinations working.

Comment: @Tetsujin well all option + <key> combos just print a character, for ex. ® for option - r.. so I guess skhd is unable to intercept it in the first place..

Comment: In which case, I'd be inclined to use either ctrl/char or opt/ctrl/char, neither of which will generate a character-code